# How to solve RunTime error 3146: ODBC --call failed in vb6.0 code?

Tags: vb6, runtime-error, odbc, database-connection

I am working on a vb6.0 application. Everything was fine then out of the blue I get the error :
RunTime error 3146: ODBC --call failed ,when I try to connect the application to the db.

```
    Public W As Workspace
    Public C As Connection
    Set W = CreateWorkspace("NewODBCWorkspace", Id, Password, dbUseODBC)
    Set C = W.OpenConnection("", dbDriverNoPrompt, False, OdbcConnectString)
```

The error occurs at the OpenConnection line. Can somebody help I really don't know why this happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with my internet connection. The moment I changed my connection to a more stable one the error went away.

Comment: So we may close this answer.

Comment: You may want to think about how your application can handle a failure like that "gracefully".  An unstable network connection could occur for your users and then they would be stuck with a meaningless error message also.